# Firebase Sqlite db file not getting uploaded

Tags: android, firebase

I have did a android Application using sqlite Database I am trying have given backup option but this code is not working stating ! What is the problem ! I have already updated google play services !

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("data/data/r.bharadwaj.inputdialog/databases/ItemDetails"));
        StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child("priceList");
        File fff=new File("data/data/r.bharadwaj.inputdialog/databases/ItemDetails");
        if(fff.exists())
        {
            showToast("File Present");
        }
        else
        {
            showToast("File Not Present");
        }
        riversRef.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                showToast("Error "+e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: add .db to your ItemDetails

Comment: Worked Thank you bro !